# How can a US agency refuse to accept certain US banknotes?

Tags: united-states, currency, us-federal-government

It has just come to my attention that the US embassy in Bern, Switzerland, accepts US dollars for the payment of passport fees [only if the notes were after 2006](https://ch.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/renewing-an-adult-passport/fee/):

> U.S. Embassy Bern
>
> Payment Options:
>
> ...
>
> - Cash: U.S. Dollars ($)
> - In-person only (No Cash in the Mail)
> - U.S dollar bills issued after 2006 only

How is this not in violation of [31 USC 5103](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/31/5103) (or is it)?  The full text of the statute is

> United States coins and currency (including Federal reserve notes and circulating notes of Federal reserve banks and national banks) are legal tender for all debts, public charges, taxes, and dues. Foreign gold or silver coins are not legal tender for debts.

Comment: This is a great question. The default answer to "legal tender" questions is to say that no debt yet exists, but legal tender also covers "public charges". Are passport fees not "public charges", "taxes", and/or "dues"?

Comment: Likely this is an anti-counterfeiting provision, as newer measures were implemented in 2006 issued currency.  It's probably due to the fact that counterfeiting in foreign countries is easier to get away with because of a lack of familiarity and lack of jurisdiction to enforce laws against counterfeiters.  U.S. Dollars are used as legal currency in a number of countries, so they do have value beyond U.S. federal jurisdictions.

Comment: @hszmv I'm sure it's an anti-counterfeiting measure, but I don't understand how one part of the US federal government can say that all US banknotes retain their status as legal tender forever while another part refuses to accept those issued before a certain date.

Comment: It is also apparently policy in the Thai embassy. The courts have not ruled whether this policy is legal, probably because nobody has sued.

Comment: If the embassy is unable to ascertain to their satisfaction that the proffered, pre-2007 items are indeed US currency,  31 USC 5103 does not apply...

Comment: @DJohnM that's also true of later banknotes.  But their policy implies that they won't attempt to determine whether the older banknotes are genuine, or even look at them.

Comment: If they know they can't, why would they waste their time (and let you waste yours alongside it) by checking?

Comment: @DJohnM, where is this "ability to ascertain" law stated? It is certainly not in 31 USC 5103.

Comment: @Nij I don't know whether they know that they can't validate the notes.  As far as I understand it, the newer notes are *easier* to validate, but that doesn't mean that the older ones are *impossible* to validate.  But to answer your question, they would take the time to check because as far as I can tell the law requires it.

Comment: @user6726 I think that what DJohnM is saying is essentially that counterfeit banknotes are *not* legal tender.  I wonder, in a case where the authenticity of a banknote is in question, where the burden of proof would fall.